# OpenXml: Convert an XElement to an OpenXmlElement

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

How would I go about converting an `XElement` to an `OpenXmlElement`? Either my google-fu fails or this has not been addressed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert a given `OpenXmlElement` to a `XElement` using the following code:

```
OpenXmlElement el = ...; // Code to get the xml element from your office doc.

// Then use XElement.Parse and the OuterXml property.
XElement xel = XElement.Parse(el.OuterXml);
```

To convert an XElement to an OpenXmlElement try the following code:

```
XElement xe = ...;
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream()))
{
  sw.Write(xe.ToString());
  sw.Flush();
  sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

  OpenXmlReader re = OpenXmlReader.Create(sw.BaseStream);

  re.Read();
  OpenXmlElement oxe = re.LoadCurrentElement();
  re.Close();
}
```

Hope, this helps.